# flutter sqflite error: flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-plugin

I am a Flutter beginner. I am using sqlflite among others including a scanbot sdk package and when running the app I get the following error

```
 flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
```

The GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java output is below:

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
      io.scanbot.sdk.flutter.ScanbotSdkPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("io.scanbot.sdk.flutter.ScanbotSdkPlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
  }
}
```

The MainActivity.kt file

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

I have switched flutter channel to stable, created a new project and moved only my /lib code and re-installed dependencies, flutter clean and still stuck. My search took me to [this](https://www.jianshu.com/p/7b551ef85e3c) Chinese code site but haven't found a solution that works for me.

I also ensured the AndroidManifest.xml file has the following line

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolved the issue by not depending on the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) package repository & using the github repo link. Its a temporary workaround [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8aOd.png)